# Temporarily block network share Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firewall, network-shares

I have access to several network shares, say

```
//serverA/share1
//serverB/share1
```

I want to temporarily prevent any program from accessing //serverA/share1. Does Windows 10 have built-in firewall? Any other mechanism available? Would I need external firewall program?

Comment: For what purpose? You can easily remove the file share and re-add it in seconds, so why complicate this?

Comment: @Appleoddity I do not want a program that I create to accidentally call this share. I do not want the ability from client machine to access this share. i.e. Production share vs Test share.

Comment: We can set the permission of the shared folder: right click the shared folder->Properties->Sharing->Advanced Sharing->Permission-> remove the specific groups or users OR deny the permission of the specific groups or users .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way was to setup entry in host file.

```
127.0.0.1 serverA
```

When I want to allow access on my local laptop, all I need is to comment this out.
If it exists, I can not access the share (attempted and failed as expected in File Explore)